# how to download file from a server that's downloading file from another server?

Tags: caching

what is it called when a client downloads file from a server that's downloading the file from another server ? Is this implementable in apache ? or php ?

Comment: looks like some kind of CDN..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mirror? I think most mirroring is done automatically using rsync (for example php.net: http://php.net/mirroring.php)